# Do not resize UI layout elements when keyboard displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

When the on-screen keyboard is displayed some UI elements in my layout shrink and/or disappear.

I do not want the underlying UI to change at all when the keyboard displays or hides.

Try try to prevent this I have added `keyboardHidden` to the configuration changes declaration in my Activity manifest believing that this would tell the system that I will handle any resizing required, but it has made no difference.

Is there a simple way to prevent any resizing when the keyboard displays and is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `adjustPan` option for the  `windowSoftInputMode` attribute in the manifest:

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

The details of the different options can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

You add it to the activity definition in the manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_activity_title"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

As above it's worth noting that using this will sometimes push part of your Activity off screen if there is a 'focused' element which would otherwise be hidden by the keyboard.